# Getting error when trying to save index path in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, nsindexpath

I am trying to save `indexPath` for the row that is being deleted from `UITableView` into `NSUSerDefaults`.

But I am getting following exception:

```
Attempt to insert non-property value '<NSIndexPath 0x834cc00> 2 indexes [0,1]
```

How can I resolve this and save data into user defaults for accessing it in other methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save it as two float values and recreate the NSIndexPath later:

so save `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.column` separately then recreate it with:

```
 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]
```

Comment: `NSIndexPath` can be more than just two values, it is a list of values. From the Apple docs: Each index in an index path represents the index into an array of children from one node in the tree to another, deeper, node. For example, the index path 1.4.3.2. In this case just saving the row and perhaps the section is all that is needed.

Comment: Makes sense. I've only used it in the scope of a tableview myself so maybe for his problem this would work.

Answer (score 2):

Add a category to `NSIndexPath`. This adds two methods that allow conversion to/from an `NSArray`. You can then save that to your defaults.

```
@implementation NSIndexPath ( ArrayRepresentation )

-(NSArray*)arrayRepresentation
{
    NSMutableArray * result = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.length ] ;
    for( int index=0, count = self.length; index < count; ++index )
    {
        [ result addObject:[ NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[ self indexAtPosition:index ] ] ] ;
    }

    return result ;
}

+(NSIndexPath*)indexPathWithArrayRepresentation:(NSArray*)array
{
    if ( array.count == 0 ) { return nil ; }

    // if array has too many items this will crash your app be careful
    NSUInteger indexes[ array.count ] ;
    for( int index=0, count = array.count; index < count; ++index )
    {
        indexes[ index ] = [ [ array objectAtIndex:index ] unsignedIntegerValue ] ;
    }

    return [ NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes length:array.count ] ;
}

@end
```

I didn't test this, might need debugging...

Comment: there are only a few types of objects you can save into a property list/user defaults: array, string, number, data and maybe a few others

Answer (score 0):

You can save to NSUserDefaults only arrays, strings, numbers, but not NSIndexPath, so you should create a method that converts NSIndexPath to an array and after that save it to NSUserDefaults.